# CSURF not working

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, csrf

[Development Env] nodejs v4.2.4 + expressjs v4.13.1 + csurf v1.8.3

I successfully installed csurf middleware but It seems like not working.
I tried submitting form without csrf input field to test it works and there was nothing err. So I inserted console.log codes into router js file

console.log(res.locals._csrf);

and I recieved 'undefined'.

I inserted input field to verify the value exist, html result also had not csrfToken

```
<input name="_csrf" value="" type="hidden">
```

What can I do? This is html source

```
<form class="form" method="post" action="/login" role="form">
                <input type="hidden" name="_csrf" value="{{_csrf}}">
                    <div class="form-group label-floating">
                        <label class="control-label" for="focusedInput1">User Name</label>
                        <input class="form-control" name="userName" id="focusedInput1" type="text">
                    </div>

                    <div class="form-group">
                      <div class="form-group label-floating">
                        <label class="control-label" for="focusedInput2">password</label>
                        <input class="form-control" name="user_pw" id="focusedInput2" type="password">
                    </div>
                    </div>

                    <div class="form-group">
                        <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary" style="float:left">Login</button>
                        <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" style="float:right" data-dismiss="modal">Cancel</button>
                    </div>
                </form>
```

and This is app.js

```
// module importing
var express = require('express'),
path = require('path'),
favicon = require('serve-favicon'),
logger = require('morgan'),
cookieParser = require('cookie-parser'),
bodyParser = require('body-parser'),
exphbs = require('express-handlebars'),
mongoose = require('mongoose'),
csrf = require('csurf');
const session = require('express-session');
const MongoStore = require('connect-mongo')(session);

var routes = require('./routes/index');
var users = require('./routes/users');

var credentials = require('./credentials.js');

var app = express();

// mongoose Setup
mongoose.connect(credentials.mongooseRsrc.collUrl);

// view engine setup
app.set('views', path.join(__dirname, 'views'));
app.engine('.hbs', exphbs({defaultLayout: 'single', extname: '.hbs'}));
app.set('view engine', '.hbs');

// uncomment after placing your favicon in /public
//app.use(favicon(path.join(__dirname, 'public', 'favicon.ico')));
app.use(logger('dev'));
app.use(bodyParser.json());
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: true }));
app.use(cookieParser(credentials.cookieSecret));
app.use(session({
    resave: false,
    saveUninitialized: false,
    secret: 'sfbsesc',
    store: new MongoStore({
        mongooseConnection: mongoose.connection
    })
}));
app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'public')));

app.use('/', routes);
app.use('/users', users);

app.use(csrf());
app.use(function(req, res, next){
    res.locals._csrf = req.csrfToken();
});
//skip
```

Comment: is `req.csrfToken()` undefined too?

Comment: A message I received is 'req.csrfToken is not a function'

Comment: router.get('/', function(req, res, next) {
 console.log(req.csrfToken());
  res.render('index', {title: 'Express',});
});

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue and worked around it by passing the token in through the controller.

In your routes controller, for your POST /login, pass in the token as an object on response.

```
router.post('/login', (req, res) => {
  res.render('login', {
    _csrfToken: req.csrfToken(),
  });
});
```

This could cause issues with other routes depending on how they're set up, but if you encounter errors saying token is invalid, you probably just need to pass it into that route as well